# When inequality exists, why variables are still complex number?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I remember when inequality exists, we can think variable  is real number.

```
     Reduce[Exp[x] < Exp[3], {x}]
```

Why this is not the case here. We need add Reals command.

```
     Reduce[Exp[x] < Exp[3], {x},Reals]
        (*   x < 3    *)
```

Comment: Consider `Exp[x] < Exp[3] /. x -> Pi I`.

Comment: when inequality exists, we can think variable is real number. Is this sentence wrong?

Comment: The quantity in the inequality is `Exp[x]`, not `x`.  With something like `x < Infinity`, `Reduce` will assume `x` is real.

Comment: Well, it seems to assume `x` is real for `x^2 < 100`, too, even though the inequality is satisfied by pure imaginary numbers. So maybe it's not clear for which functions `f[x] < a` implies `x` will be assumed to be real and for which it will not.

Comment: OK, it seem  in inequality  the key is algebraic operation, +, -, *, /,   powers and roots of rational number,  only with  these operation , variable is real number, otherwise is complex number.